# Combining two pandas data frame with multilevel index

Tags: pandas

Below is the original dataframe

```
    Week_No item_Number     Inside__Outside
4   1.2014  3164018114707537    INSIDE
6   1.2014  50010EJ654990       INSIDE
19  1.2014  304400JE130142      INSIDE
29  1.2014  3164018114725810    INSIDE
31  1.2014  3164018114711298    INSIDE
35  1.2014  3164018114707546    OUTSIDE
36  1.2014  3164018114711299    OUTSIDE
41  1.2014  3164018114727381    INSIDE
54  1.2014  50010EJ655470       OUTSIDE
145 1.2014  304400TS135379      INSIDE
```

After this i grouped like this

```
df = df.groupby(['Week_No','Inside__Outside']).agg(['count'])
```

after which a combined dataframe

```
                            item_Number
                               count
Week_No   Inside__Outside   
1.2014          INSIDE          51
                OUTSIDE         8
2.2014          INSIDE          91
                OUTSIDE         16
3.2014          INSIDE          92
                OUTSIDE         7
4.2014          INSIDE          76
                OUTSIDE         5
```

Now have two dataframe

```
df1                                 
                             item_Number
                                 count
Week_No     Inside__Outside     
1.2015      INSIDE                18
2.2015      INSIDE                48
3.2015      INSIDE                87
4.2015      INSIDE                54
5.2015      INSIDE                61
6.2015      INSIDE                46
7.2015      INSIDE                83
8.2015      INSIDE                41
9.2015      INSIDE                34
```

And

```
df2                                 
                                 item_Number
                                     count
    Week_No     Inside__Outside     
    1.2015      OUTSIDE                   8
    2.2015      OUTSIDE                   4
    3.2015      OUTSIDE                   7
    4.2015      OUTSIDE                   4
    5.2015      OUTSIDE                   1
    6.2015      OUTSIDE                   6
    7.2015      OUTSIDE                   8
    8.2015      OUTSIDE                   4
    9.2015      OUTSIDE                   3
```

Now I want to sum based on week. i.e. output of the the two data frame

```
Week_No     total   
    1.2015      18
    2.2015      48
    3.2015      87
    4.2015      54
    5.2015      61
    6.2015      46
    7.2015      83
    8.2015      41
    9.2015      34
```

I thought of selecting the data first and then would add them manually but that doesn't seem to be efficient. Also since this is multilevel index I am unable to select data based on Week_no. Also please dont look at the absolute numbers in count column. My question is specific to operations on multilevel index dataframe.

Comment: Can you post code and raw input data to reproduce your dfs, also your df's are not that informative as the total is indentical to the count anyway as you only have 1 value per week, you can do `df.groupby(level=0).sum()`

Comment: Hi @EdChum, I have added the code , original dataframe as well as output. Please ignore the absolute values in a column as this is just an example. I want to know how the operations on pandas dataframe with multilevel index works. I have added it in question as well.

Comment: can you try `df1.add(df2, level=0)`

Comment: Tried doing that and I get an error saying `Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous`

Comment: If you sum the two up the respective rows should add up. That way, for `1.2015` in the output dataframe should have 26 and not 18. Hence, I think the output that you have given in the question is incorrect. Could you please check if my answer below is what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append them together and group them by the first level -

```
In [118]: df1
Out[118]: 
                        item_Number
                              count
Week_No Inside__Outside            
1.2015  INSIDE                   18
2.2015  INSIDE                   48
3.2015  INSIDE                   87
4.2015  INSIDE                   54
5.2015  INSIDE                   61
6.2015  INSIDE                   46
7.2015  INSIDE                   83
8.2015  INSIDE                   41
9.2015  INSIDE                   34

In [119]: df2
Out[119]: 
                        item_Number
                              count
Week_No Inside__Outside            
1.2015  OUTSIDE                   8
2.2015  OUTSIDE                   4
3.2015  OUTSIDE                   7
4.2015  OUTSIDE                   4
5.2015  OUTSIDE                   1
6.2015  OUTSIDE                   6
7.2015  OUTSIDE                   8
8.2015  OUTSIDE                   4
9.2015  OUTSIDE                   3

In [120]: df1.append(df2).groupby(level=0).sum()
Out[120]: 
        item_Number
              count
Week_No            
1.2015           26
2.2015           52
3.2015           94
4.2015           58
5.2015           62
6.2015           52
7.2015           91
8.2015           45
9.2015           37
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of the `Inside__Outside` column from your index, since you are not using it to join the two tables.

---

Let's start with with the two dataframes you give in your example:

```
data_1_df
Out[35]: 
                         item_Number count
Week_No Inside__Outside                   
1.2015  INSIDE                          18
2.2015  INSIDE                          48
3.2015  INSIDE                          87
4.2015  INSIDE                          54
5.2015  INSIDE                          61
6.2015  INSIDE                          46
7.2015  INSIDE                          83
8.2015  INSIDE                          41
9.2015  INSIDE                          34
```

and

```
data_2_df
Out[36]: 
                         item_Number count
Week_No Inside__Outside                   
1.2015  OUTSIDE                          8
2.2015  OUTSIDE                          4
3.2015  OUTSIDE                          7
4.2015  OUTSIDE                          4
5.2015  OUTSIDE                          1
6.2015  OUTSIDE                          6
7.2015  OUTSIDE                          8
8.2015  OUTSIDE                          4
9.2015  OUTSIDE                          3
```

You can stack them one on top of the other, group on `Week_No` and sum on `item_Number count`:

```
data_3_df = (
    pd.concat([data_1_df, data_2_df])
    .reset_index()
    .groupby('Week_No')
    .agg({'item_Number count': sum}
)
```

This gives the sum for every week, for both `INSIDE` and `OUTSIDE`:

```
data_3_df
Out[52]: 
         item_Number count
Week_No                   
1.2015                  26
2.2015                  52
3.2015                  94
4.2015                  58
5.2015                  62
6.2015                  52
7.2015                  91
8.2015                  45
9.2015                  37
```